# Refactoring rails nested methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, parameters, model

Im trying to refactor my code in the Team model. Teams has:many Projections, and Projections has stats for a player (goals, assists, hits etc). I want to implement one method that can tally a specific total if you pass it the parameter you are looking for.

Something like this, where I could call:
example_team.total(goals)
or
example_team.total(assists)

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord

# def total(value)
  #   total = 0    
  #   self.projections.each do |projection|
  #     total += projection.value
  #   end 
  #   return total
  # end
```

The issue im having is that im essentially trying to pass a method name within a different method as a parameter. Im getting errors when im trying to do this. How can I get this refactoring to work???

This is my current unfactored code:

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord

def goals
    total = 0    
    self.projections.each do |projection|
      total += projection.goals
    end 
    return total
  end 

  def assists
    total = 0    
    self.projections.each do |projection|
      total += projection.assists
    end 
    return total
  end 

  def pp_points
    total = 0    
    self.projections.each do |projection|
      total += projection.pp_points
    end 
    return total
  end 
  
  def hits
    total = 0    
    self.projections.each do |projection|
      total += projection.hits
    end 
    return total
  end 

  def blocks
    total = 0    
    self.projections.each do |projection|
      total += projection.blocks
    end 
    return total
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

To send a method dynamically you can use [public_send](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/public_send).

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  def total(field)
    total = 0    
    self.projections.each do |projection|
      total += projection.public_send(field)
    end
    return total
  end
end
```

To simplify the example we can use [sum](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/sum) that takes a symbol as an argument.

```
class Team < ApplicationRecord
  def total(field)
    projections.sum(field)
  end
end
```

To make it work you should use something like this `example_team.total(:goals)`.